# Gmail Login in android

Tags: android, authentication, gmail

In my app,there is a gmail login section where user can login to the app using his/her gmail credentials.I had implemented with the help of oauth.

But the problem is , it shows errors for some gmail login.ie after inputing the gmail username/password and  alllow access ,it shows the callback url which i put and shows webpage error.
For call back, i used "http://localhost". By using this ,some of the gmail users(my friends )can successfully loggedin.

Can anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Can u please share your code for login to gmail or share  any tutorials . Thanks .

Comment: code which u have used for authenticating gmail .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason behind this.

ie it is gmail privacy problem. In gmail settings,if we enable "always use https" and suppose our call back url is "http://localhost",then it will not taken and shows error.Since in our manifest file, we mentioned scheme = "http" .